# Не могу убрать Администрацию из списка рейтинга по параметрам

Tags: php

```
// Как Убрать пользователя с правами Админа из рейтинга где права "bitwar"
// 
<?php
include ('system/func.php');
$title = 'Зал славы';
include ('system/header.php');
auth(); // Закроем от гостей

$set['p_str'] = 10;
$k_post = 1000;
$k_page = k_page($k_post,$set['p_str']);
$page = page($k_page);
$start = $set['p_str']*$page-$set['p_str'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `bot` = '0' ORDER BY     
`str`+`def`+`max_health`+`max_energy` DESC, `online` DESC LIMIT $start, 
$set[p_str]");
echo "<div class='block'>";
if($page == 1){

$n_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `bot` = '0' ORDER BY 
`str`+`def`+`max_health`+`max_energy` DESC, `online` DESC LIMIT 1");
$n_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($n_1);

echo ico('icons','dost.png')." <font color='yellow'><b>Самый сильный</b> 
</font><div class='mb10'></div>";
if(!empty($n_1['avatar'])){
echo "<img src='/images/avatars/$n_1[avatar]' style='max-width:110px; 
height:140px;'>";
}else{
echo "<img src='/images/profile228/profile.jpg' style='width:110px; 
height:140px;'></div>";
}



echo "<br>";
echo icons_user($n_1['id'])." <a>$n_1[login]</a><br>";
echo ico('icons','str.png')." Сила: $n_1[str]<br>";
echo ico('icons','def.png')." Защита: $n_1[def]<br>";
echo ico('icons','health.png')." Жизнь: $n_1[max_health]<br>";
echo ico('icons','energy.png')." Энергия: $n_1[max_energy]</oh>";
echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div><div class='mb10'></div>";
}

while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
$i++;
if($i < 11){
if($myID == $post[id])echo "<div style='background-color: darkred;'>";
else echo "<div>";
echo $i+$start.". ".icons_user($post[id])." <a href='/profile/$post[id]' 
data-ajax>$post[login],</a> ".ico('icons','level.png')." $post[level]ур. 
<br>";
echo "Сумма: ".ico('icons','sum_stat.png')." ". 
($post['str']+$post['def']+$post['max_health']+$post['max_energy']);
echo "</div><div class='mb10'></div>";
}
}
str('?',$k_page,$page); // Вывод страниц
echo "</div>";
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `bot` = '0' ORDER BY 
`str`+`def`+`max_health`+`max_energy` DESC, `online` DESC");
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
$a++;
if($post[id] == $myID){
if($a <= 1000)echo "<div class='block'><span class='info'>Вы находитесь на 
<b>$a</b> месте в рейтинге!</span></div>";
else echo "<div class='mb10'></div><div class='block'>Вы не участвуете в 
рейтинге...</div>";

}

}

include ('system/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: или как вариант убрать пользователя из рейтинга с id =1 и 47

Comment: А как узнаете, что пользователь администратор? так и вносите, если админ, не показывать.

Answer (score 0):

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `bot` = '0'    AND `id` != 1 AND `id` != 47  ORDER BY
`str`+`def`+`max_health`+`max_energy`  DESC, `online` DESC LIMIT $start, 
$set[p_str]");